# Nodejs BotFrameworkAdapter is not a constructor error

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying to deploy bot developed using botframework v4. Even if everything seems correct I keep getting 
"Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
TypeError: BotFrameworkAdapter is not a constructor"

I also verified that the appId and password is correctly passed to the code below:

```
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: endpointConfig.appId || process.env.microsoftAppID,
    appPassword: endpointConfig.appPassword || process.env.microsoftAppPassword
});
```

Could anyone let me know what may be the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: That's an odd one. You have: `const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');` and you don't have BotFrameworkAdapter defined or instantiated in any other way? You can try updating your package with `npm i -s botbuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

After some testing, I believe your issue is likely that you have:

```
const BotFrameworkAdapter = require('botbuilder');
```

and not:

```
const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');
```

The brackets are required around `BotFameworkAdapter`

---

If you're not aware as to why (you probably are--this is more for posterity), it's called ["destructuring assignment"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Without brackets,

`const BotFrameworkAdapter = require('botbuilder')`

sets BotFrameworkAdapter to *all* of `botbuilder`.

If you do it this way, you could access `BotFrameworkAdapter` with:

`BotFrameworkAdapter.BotFrameworkAdapter`

---

By using

`const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder')`

it sets `BotFrameworkAdapter` to the exported `BotFrameworkAdapter` class, instead of `botbuilder`, as a whole.

Note: You could also use:

`const BotFrameworkAdapter = require('botbuilder').BotFrameworkAdapter`

Comment: The index.js file is the one I copied from one of the template generated from yo generator, so it should be the correct one.

Comment: @AshyAshcsi I just ran all 6 templates (3 JS, 3 TS) from `yo botbuilder` and they all worked. Are you still having issues? With which template? Can you edit your `index.js` (or equivalent) into your question? You may also want to update your botbuilder generator with `npm install -g yo generator-botbuilder`

Comment: yes, I deleted the bot and copied the files again. It is working fine now. Is there a way to use variables from azure app settings instead of the .bot file ? just like we did for botframework v3.

Comment: i am still facing the error in my case as
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: BotFrameworkAdapter is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/moblizeit/code-repo/apps/business-card-scanner/functions/lib/index.js:71:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)

Comment: @MoblizeIT Please open a new StackOverflow issue with your problem so you can include your code. Feel free to link me to it.